# 参加する為にはパソコンが必要ですか

Tags: aibo-developer

"aibo-developer"
パソコンが無くてスマホだけでこのイベントに参加する事はできませんか

Answer (score 2):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。

aibo デベロッパープログラムは、aibo のAPI（Web API）の公開にともない、
aibo との連携サービス・アプリ等を開発するために必要なライセンスプログラムです。
ファンミーティングなどの aibo のイベントとは異なります。

詳しくは、下記の aibo デベロッパープログラムの Web サイトをご確認ください。

https://aibo.sony.jp/developer/

> aiboデベロッパープログラム
> aiboを活用して新しいライフスタイルを作りませんか？

また、aibo Web APIは PC やサーバー、スマートフォンなど
インターネットにアクセス出来る任意のデバイスから実行が可能です。
デバイスによって実行可能な API の種類や実行内容に違いはありません。

上記でも解決されない場合は、aiboオーナーサポートへお問い合わせください。
https://aibo.sony.jp/support/contact.html?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/_contact

> 「aiboの飼い方、ご購入前の相談など、aiboに関するすべてのお問い合わせは以下のaibo専用窓口へお問い合わせください。」

・メールでのお問い合わせ
　https://www.sony.jp/support/aibo/inquiry_mail/?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/contact/_mail

> 上記リンク先において、注意事項に同意いただいた上、 　「
> 同意してメールで問い合わせる」ボタンを押してください。

・チャットでのお問い合わせ
　https://www.sony.jp/support/aibo/inquiry/chat.html?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/contact/_chat

> 上記リンク先にある「上記内容を確認して自動往々サービスを開始する」を押してください。

・LINE でのお問い合わせ
　https://www.sony.jp/support/inquiry_line.html?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/contact/_line

> LINE公式アカウントから、お問い合わせをいただけます。
> リンク先にある「友だち追加」ボタンをクリックするか、「QRコード」を読み取ってください。

また、Stackoverflow への質問はプログラミングのことに限定していただきますようお願いいたします。
詳しくはこちらをご参照ください。
https://aibo.sony.jp/support/contact.html?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/_contact#devevisu

> ・質問の例
> 「〇〇のプログラムを実行したいのですが、どうすればできますか？」
> 「APIでエラーが発生します。原因は何でしょうか？」

今後とも aibo デベロッパープログラムをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム

Answer (score 1):

結論から言うと、[公式ドキュメント](https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs)の[API 実行の流れ](https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs#api-%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%AE%E6%B5%81%E3%82%8C)によると、HTTP リクエストを送ることによって操作する一種の RESTful な仕組のようなので、「PC が必須」というわけではないでしょう。

説明では Python などでプログラムを組んでそれから HTTP リクエストを送信し、レポンスを分析し、……という流れで動かしているようです。

Python はスマホでも実行できる環境があったと思いますが、普通に Python プログラムを実行するのであれば、PC で実行環境を整える方が簡単だと思います。しかし、ともかく PC が必須なわけではないでしょう。

---

また、[**aiboビジュアルプログラミング**](https://aibo.sony.jp/fan/visual_programming/)というサービスから Web API を使う話であれば、

> Q : スマートフォンやタブレットでも使えますか？
> A : aibo ビジュアルプログラミングは、iPadOS、Windows PC、Mac
> でお楽しみいただけます。
> iOS12 以前の iPad でも表示はされますが、プロジェクトの保存機能がご利用できないなど、一部機能のみのご利用となります。
>
> その他の動作環境につきましては、下記の通りです。
>
> Windows 8.1 以降の場合：Google Chrome
> macOS X.10.10 Yosemite 以降の場合：Google Chrome、Safari ver.11 以降
> iPadOS 13 以降の場合：Safari ver.13 以降

とありますね。Android / iOS は対象外のようです。